# Too cold for transmission?

Tags: wireless, transmission

I've got a weather station which only intermittently sends data. The technical support claims it's because the receiver must be in a room above 15C.
It has got batteries, but even if I connect it to mains electricity it still fails.

Does it really make such a difference if it is 12C or 16C?

Comment: It's certainly possible to design circuits that don't work at low temperatures but it's usually not the goal. And designing for operation down to 0 C is not extraordinarily difficult (if batteries aren't involved). But without knowing more about the actual circuit you're working with, we can only give wild guesses what is going on.

Comment: I can imagine that some sensors like air pressure are specified / calibrated for room temperature and a designer chose to shutdown the device if it gets too cold. But I'm only guessing here. Your question lacks a lot of detail and is potentially off topic for EE anyway. It might make a good example question for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics

Comment: Let me get this straight, the manufacturer specifies the minimum operating temperature as 15C, and you are complaining it doesn't work at 12C?  If so there is no problem here other than your understanding of "minimum required".

Comment: @jippie, a sensor in a weather station that only works at room temperature would seem kind of pointless, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ThePhoton True, but the receiver end is usually for indoor use and IIRC air pressure sensors are often very sensitive to temperature.

Comment: I'm confused. If the station intermittently  *sends* data, what does that have to do with the temperature of the *receiver*?

Answer (score 7):

Temperature effects electronics in different ways.  Here's some of them:

- Digital logic tends to run faster at colder temps.  The same effects also work on analog circuits, but sometimes we call it something other than "faster".  Normally faster is better, but there is such a thing as too fast.  If it is too fast, sometimes you can start to violate your timing requirements (setup/hold time) of your flip flops.
- The values of caps and resistors change with temperature.  Sometimes in a good way, and sometimes in a bad way.  Often, analog circuits start to behave differently.  For example, a simple oscillator that uses an RC timing constant to run at a given frequency will have that frequency changed as the temp changes.   If your weather station uses a wireless link, it is possible that the carrier frequency of that RF signal is changing enough that the receiver can no longer receive it.
- Batteries work less-well at lower temps.  Batteries use a chemical reaction to work, and those reactions slow down as the temp drops.  (I know you're not using batteries, but I put this in here for others who might read it.)
- Many semiconductors are rated to run on a consumer temperature range of 0C to 70C, ambient.
- As the temp drops, the humidity goes up.  Dew can form, which can combine with dirt/dust/etc. and short out electronics.
- The analog characteristics of transistors change as the temp changes.  This can effect circuits like PLL's, which often rely on current-sources made from transistors.  If the PLL is not designed to run  <0C, then it might fail.

There are many other things that can fail due to cold temps, I only mentioned some common ones.

So any of these things can result in your weather station to stop working.  Although it seems silly to me that a weather station would not work in, um, WEATHER.

Comment: It seems he is saying the *reciever* is not working at the cold temperature, not the weather station, which would be silly as you say.  +1 for a good rundown on temperature effects on electronics.

Comment: How can you be sure it's the receiver not the transmitter that's at fault? The temperature could be making the Tx drift off-frequency or dew could be stopping xtal circuit from running.